# How to only apply "Require status checks to pass before merging" branch protection for code changes, but not for documentation changes?

Tags: github, github-actions

I have enabled branch protection for the default branch (`master`), with "Require status checks to pass before merging".

The status check that must pass before merging is called "Release", the final job of a full CI/CD pipeline.

Now, the issue I'm facing is that I don't want this required status check to apply for e.g. updates to documentation (`/docs`, `README.md`, etc.). Why would I require a full deploy to production for minor edits to Markdown files? Instead, I would rather like to have a required status check for documentation consisting of Markdown linting.

How can I achieve this?